# App crash with "Unable to restore previously selected frame" message

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview

I can't figure out why that code leads to app crash.

AppDelegate.h

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.rootViewController = [[[RootViewController alloc]init]autorelease];

    [self.window setRootViewController:self.rootViewController];


    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Here is RootViewController.m code

```
-(void)loadView
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    [view release];
}
```

I get that message in the debugger

```
Unable to restore previously selected frame.
```

[image: Here is screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loadView` is supposed to *set* the view. It is called when `self.view` is nil. Now you're calling `[self.view addSubview:view];` UIKit calls `loadView`, and that creates an infinite recursion. You're supposed to do `self.view = view;` here.

Answer (score 1):

loadView is responsible to set the view first. you missed to do that. Instead you added a view to self.view.

Change the code by below line:

```
self.view = view;
```

instead of `[self.view addSubview:view];`

Also it is advisable to call `[super loadView]` before returning from the function.